# How should I clear fields in generic static class?

Tags: c#, generics, static

I have a class that goes like this:

```
public static class Messenger<T>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    public static void DoSomethingWithEventTable() //Somehow fills eventTable
    public static void Clear() 
    {
        eventTable.Clear();
    }
}
```

Now, I called `DoSomethingWithEventTable` two times somewhere in my program, like this:

```
Messenger<int>.DoSomethingWithEventTable();
Messenger<float>.DoSomethingWithEventTable();
```

I want to clear `eventTable` for every `Messenger<T>`. How should I do it? Should I call `Clear` for every type that I have put in generics, like this:

```
Messenger<int>.Clear();
Messenger<float>.Clear();
```

Or will it be enough to do something silly like this once:

```
Messenger<string>.Clear();
```

**UPD:** Basic experiments show that I should clear the Messenger for every used T. Now could somebody come with better design for the classes?

The more detailed version of what I am using now:

```
static public class Messenger<T>
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    static public void AddListener(string eventType, Callback<T> handler)
    {
        // Obtain a lock on the event table to keep this thread-safe.
        lock (eventTable)
        {
            // Create an entry for this event type if it doesn't already exist.
            if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
            {
                eventTable.Add(eventType, null);
            }
            // Add the handler to the event.
            eventTable[eventType] = (Callback<T>)eventTable[eventType] + handler;
        }
    }

    static public void RemoveListener(string eventType, Callback<T> handler)
    {
        // Obtain a lock on the event table to keep this thread-safe.
        lock (eventTable)
        {
            // Only take action if this event type exists.
            if (eventTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
            {
                // Remove the event handler from this event.
                eventTable[eventType] = (Callback<T>)eventTable[eventType] - handler;

                // If there's nothing left then remove the event type from the event table.
                if (eventTable[eventType] == null)
                {
                    eventTable.Remove(eventType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static public void Invoke(string eventType, T arg1)
    {
        Delegate d;
        // Invoke the delegate only if the event type is in the dictionary.
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out d))
        {
            // Take a local copy to prevent a race condition if another thread
            // were to unsubscribe from this event.
            Callback<T> callback = (Callback<T>)d;

            // Invoke the delegate if it's not null.
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(arg1);
            }
        }
    }

    static public void Clear()
    {
        eventTable.Clear();
    }
}
```

It is also important that I have another classes `Messenger` (non-generic, yeah) and `Messenger<T,M>`, and maybe someday I would even need something like `Messenger<T,M,N>`, etc.

Comment: I don't see you using T anywhere... What is it used for?

Comment: The class is actually bigger, and has methods like `public static void AddListener(string eventType, Callback<T> handler)`, but that is really out of scope of the question.

Comment: @Rafal If they were not static that comment would make a lot more sense. But since they are static they are in fact separate "classes" from the perspective of static members.

Comment: Why not make `eventTable` a `Dictionary<string, Callback<T>>`? Also, `Invoke` and `Clear` need locks too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `Messenger<T>` type will have it's own copy of eventTable so you will need to call Clear() for every different T you have used.

As shown by this test:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {    
        static class MyClass<T>
        {
            public static List<int> Member = new List<int>();
        }

        [Test]
        public void StaticTest()
        {
            var m1 = MyClass<int>.Member;
            var m2 = MyClass<string>.Member;

            Assert.AreNotSame(m1, m2);
        }
}
```

Comment: @Rafal, no, you are in fact wrong. Try for yourself or read this for example: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/09/05/225955.aspx . I understand your intention is not to confuse.

Comment: @Rafal, I realize it's static but multiple copies of the static member are created. See the example I've added.

Comment: @flindeberg yes I can see that now.

Answer (score 3):

Since

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

does not depend on `<T>`, create a static "handler" for all event tables.

IE

```
public static class TableHandler {
    ICollection<Dictionary<string, Delegate>> tables = new List<Dictionary<string, Delegate>>();

    public void Add(Dictionary<string, Delegate> item) 
    {
        tables.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var item in tables) item.Clear();
        tables.Clear();
    }
}
```

and ensure that `DoSomethingWithEventTable()` adds the event table to the `TableHandler`.

Might not be the best overall solution, but it helps you keep track of the tables with the current design.

**EDIT:**

I tried to google for a way to find all generic variants of a static class, but I did not find a way. Does anyone know of a way to do that?